# differences between StringBuilder in Java and C#

Tags: c#, java, stringbuilder

I am converting Java code to C#. The StringBuilder class in Java seems to have many more methods than the C# one. I am interested in (say) the Java functionality

```
sb.indexOf(s);
sb.charAt(i);
sb.deleteCharAt(i);
```

which seems to be missing in C#.

I suppose the first two could be modelled by

```
sb.ToString().IndexOf(s);
sb.ToString().CharAt(i);
```

but would the third operate on a copy of the contents of the sb rather than the actual contents?

Is there a common way of adding this functionality to all missing methods?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the Chars member collection for .charAt.  Similarly, you can use .Remove(i,1) to remove a single char at position i.

Comment: @Joe. Where is Chars - could you give an example. (I looked in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2839d5h5%28VS.71%29.aspx and didn't find anything)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder_members%28VS.71%29.aspx

It's a property.  In C#, it's done via the indexer (e.g.  mySb[idx] )

Answer (score 2):

For the third you could use the [Remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.remove.aspx) method:

```
sb.Remove(i, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use extension methods like the following:

```
    static class Extensions
    {
        public static int IndexOf(this StringBuilder sb, string value)
        {
            return sb.ToString().IndexOf(value);
        }

//if you must use CharAt instead of indexer
        public static int CharAt(this StringBuilder sb, int index)
        {
            return sb[index];
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Yuriy I am coming from Java and so naturally look for an identical method first. Thanks for pointing out indexer.

Answer (score 0):

StringBuilder has an indexer, that means you can simply access single characters using sb[i]