# Please explain extension methods to me

Tags: c#, vb.net, extension-methods

I just looked at this posting: [What is the best or most interesting use of Extension Methods you’ve seen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954198/what-is-the-best-or-most-interesting-use-of-extension-methods-youve-seen)

I've never heard of extension methods. Do they apply to every language?

What is the point of them? In that particular posting I did not understand the example.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/extension-methods+c%23

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are available to C# and VB.  They allow you to simulate the addition of methods to classes that are not under your control.

You could, for instance, you could add a [`WordCount`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) method to string.

So instead of

`MyStringUtils.WordCount( "some string" )`

You could just write `"some string".WordCount()`.

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static int WordCount(this String str)
    {
        return MyStringUtils.WordCount( str );
    }
}
```

This is strictly "syntactic sugar" and aids in readability.  You're essentially creating a static method that will be shown in the IntelliSense for the target type.

Answer (score 7):

No, they do not apply to every language.  They are a language-specific feature, offered by C# and Visual Basic (other languages may have adopted them since, I don't know).

The point of them is to provide a convenient syntax for calling utility methods on a class or interface.  In C# 2, a utility method would be called through a static class, passing the argument in the normal way:

```
IEnumerable<string> someStrings;
int count = EnumerableHelpers.Count(someStrings);
```

With extension methods, this can be written more conveniently using something that looks like normal member method syntax:

```
int count = someStrings.Count();
```

even though Count() is not a member of the `IEnumerable<string>` interface.  So extension methods let you *appear to* add members to classes or interfaces that you don't control.

Answer (score 1):

> do they apply to every language?

No, but some languages have the same feature, though not necessarily under the same name. Those I know about are [Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW1) and [Groovy](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Groovy+Categories), where the feature is called "Categories".