# Generating CSV file from SqlDataSource/GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, sqldatasource

I need to be able to generate a basic CSV file of the results returned from an SqlDataSource/GridView upon the user clicking a button, then allow them to save this file.

Is this simple to do?

Thanks

Comment: Do you actually want a .csv, or are you settling for a .csv because spreadsheets are so complex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a SqlDataSource then you can get a DataTable out of it like this:

```
var dv = new DataView();
var dt = new DataTable();
dv = (DataView)mySQLDataSource.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
dt = dv.ToTable();
```

I wrote a set of [extension methods to do DataTable to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954198/what-is-the-best-or-most-interesting-use-of-extension-methods-youve-seen/954225#954225), which you should be able to use easily.

The rest of your code would be pretty simple then:

```
var csv = dt.ToCSV();
```

Here is a full example using this very method.

The Markup:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="SO.WebUI._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="EmployeeId"
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceLocal">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="EmployeeId" HeaderText="EmployeeId" InsertVisible="False"
                ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="EmployeeId" Visible="False" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Birthdate" HeaderText="Birthdate" SortExpression="Birthdate" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

    <!-- This is the button to export CSV! -->
    <asp:Button ID="btnToCSV" runat="server" Text="Export to CSV" OnClick="GetCSV" />

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceLocal" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:StackOverflowExamplesConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Employee]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
</asp:Content>
```

And the code-behind:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void GetCSV(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataView dv = (DataView)SqlDataSourceLocal.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
        var dt = dv.ToTable();

        var csv = dt.ToCSV();

        WriteToOutput(csv, "export.csv", "text/csv");
    }

    private void WriteToOutput(String csv, String fileName, String mimeType)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = mimeType;
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment;filename={0}", fileName));
        Response.Write(csv);
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

There you go. The only thing not included here is the extension method source, but since I've linked to it, you should have no problems getting that into a static class.

Answer (score 0):

For a GridView you could use this:

```
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("file.csv");

            // Write columns
            writer.Write(myGridView.Columns[0].HeaderText);
            for (int i = 1; i < myGridView.Columns.Count; i++)
                writer.Write("," + myGridView.Columns[i].HeaderText);

            writer.Write("\n");

            // Write values
            for (int x = 0; x < myGridView.Rows.Count; x++)
            {
                writer.Write(myGridView.Rows[x].Cells[0].Text);
                for (int i = 1; i < myGridView.Rows[x].Cells.Count; i++)
                    writer.Write("," + myGridView.Rows[x].Cells[i].Text);

                writer.Write("\n");
            }

            writer.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

private void button13_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // export to .csv
       {
           //OnExportGridToCSV();

```
       StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\scripts\\file.csv");

       // Write columns
       writer.Write(dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText);
       for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
           writer.Write("," + dataGridView1.Columns[i].HeaderText);

       writer.Write("\n");

       // Write values
       for (int x = 0; x < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; x++)
       {
           writer.Write(dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[0].FormattedValue.ToString());
           for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells.Count; i++)
               writer.Write("," + dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[i].FormattedValue.ToString());

           writer.Write("\n");

           textBox5.Text = ("Row " + (x + 1).ToString() + " of " + dataGridView1.Rows.Count + " exported."); // progress indicator
       }


       writer.Close();



       // open up the newly created file in excel 

       Process proc = new Process();
       proc.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("excel.exe", "C:\\scripts\\file.csv");
       proc.Start();
   }
```