# Strongly typed parsing of CSV-files

Tags: c#, csv, text-parsing, filehelpers

So after about an hour's worth of pulling my hair in desperation, I decided to follow the advice from, like, everybody in here and ***not implement my own CSV-parser***.

So I went with [FileHelpers](https://www.filehelpers.net) instead.

But I am having a bit of trouble using it correctly.

My CSV-file looks something like this:

```
50382018,50319368,eBusiness Manager,IT02,3350_FIB4,IT,2480
50370383,50373053,CRM Manager,IT01,3200_FIB3,xyz,2480
50320067,50341107,"VP, Business Information Officer",IT03,3200_FI89,xyz,2480
50299061,50350088,Project Expert,IT02,8118_FI09,abc,2480
```

My need for FileHelpers (and, specifically `CsvEngine`) is in line 3 - notice third column enclosed in quotes since it has an internal comma (which is otherwise used as delimiter).

My code to read the file is this:

```
var co = new FileHelpers.Options.CsvOptions("Employee", columnDeliminator, 7);
var ce = new CsvEngine(co);

var records = ce.ReadFile(pathToCSVFile);
```

It works fine - sort of. It correctly parses the lines and recognizes the values with enclosed delimiters.

But.

The return value of the `ReadFile()`-method is `object[]`. And the contents of it appears to be some kind of dynamic type.

It looks something like this - where the columns are named "Field_1", "Field_2" etc.

[image: Automatically generated return type]

I have created a "data class" intended to hold the parsed lines It looks like this:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string DepartmentPosition;
    public string ParentDepartmentPosition;
    public string JobTitle;
    public string Role;
    public string Location;
    public string NameLocation;
    public string EmployeeStatus;
}
```

Is there a way to have FileHelpers' `CsvEngine` class to return strongly typed data?

If I could just use the "basic" parser of FileHelpers, I could use this code:

```
var engine = new FileHelperEngine<Employee>();
var records = engine.ReadFile("Input.txt");
```

Is there a way to have `CsvEngine` return instances of my "Employee" class? Or do I have to write my own mapping code to support this?

Comment: Will the CSV file have headers? Have you looked at using [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@shamp00 has the correct answer - and I also found it at [FileHelper escape delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18529845/filehelper-escape-delimiter) .

I took my model class and decorated each property on it as suggested:

*(I probably don't need to decorate all properties, but it works for now)*

```
[DelimitedRecord((","))]
public class Employee
{
    [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth)]
    public string DepartmentPosition;
    [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth)]
    public string ParentDepartmentPosition;
    [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth)]
    public string JobTitle;
    [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth)]
    public string Role;
    [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth)]
    public string Location;
    [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth)]
    public string NameLocation;
    [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth)]
    public string EmployeeStatus;
}
```

Now I just need this code:

```
TextReader reader = new StreamReader(contents);
var engine = new FileHelperEngine<Employee>()
{
    Options = { IgnoreFirstLines = 1 }
};
var myRecords = engine.ReadStream(reader);
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://www.filehelpers.net/example/QuickStart/ReadFileDelimited/) worked for me for a one simple way:

First in your class, it needs a couple decorators:

**Edit** Use the FieldQuoted decorator to parse anything in quotes and ignore the included comma

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
class Person
{
    [FieldQuoted]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Int32)]
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public string State { get; set; }
}
```

`DelimitedRecord` for the class and the expected delimiter (this could be a problem if things change later.

and FieldConverter for it appears anything other than string.

Then change your reading method slightly:

```
var fhr = new FileHelperEngine<Person>();            
var readLines = fhr.ReadFile(pathToFile);
```

and then it works, strongly typed:

```
foreach(var person in readLines)
{
   Console.WriteLine(person.Name);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Austin, you realize that you are suggesting that I try something, that I specifically wrote in my question as not being possible? .

Comment: @Austin's answer looks correct to me. If you want the engine to return an array of concrete classes, you cannot use `CsvEngine`. You would need to do the mapping yourself. Using `FileHelperEngine<Employee>` is the best approach, but you need to decorate the class with `[DelimitedRecord(",")]` and decorate the _JobTitle_ property with `[FieldQuoted(QuoteMode.OptionalForRead)]`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, @JesperLundStocholm why does that not work as a solution?
Also, I tried to guess why it didn't, the "Quoted word, with comma" in which case I showed how to get around that.

Comment: @AustinTFrench I cannot use your suggestion since it chokes on line three with the enclosed delimiter. However - I found the solution and managed to augment your suggestion. See below :-)

Answer (score 0):

Using [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) as a viable alternative and assuming the CSV file has no headers,

a mapping can be created for the `Employee` class like

```
public sealed class EmployeeClassMap : ClassMap<Employee> {
    public EmployeeClassMap() {
        Map(_ => _.Location).Index(0);
        Map(_ => _.NameLocation).Index(1);
        Map(_ => _.JobTitle).Index(2);
        //...removed for brevity
    }
}
```

Where the index is mapped to a respective property on the strongly typed object model.

To use this mapping, you need to register the mapping in the configuration.

```
using (var textReader = new StreamReader(pathToCSVFile)) {
    var csv = new CsvReader(textReader);
    csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<EmployeeClassMap>();

    var records = csv.GetRecords<Employee>();

    //...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If this lib not work, you can also try to use built-in .Net CSV parser TextFieldParser. For ex: https://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/built-in-net-csv-parser/

ADDED:
For types (with auto convert):

```
    static void run()
    {
        // split with any lib line of CSV
        string[] line = new string[]{"john", "doe", "201"};
        // needed prop names of class
        string[] propNames = "fname|lname|room".Split('|');

        Person p = new Person();
        parseLine<Person>(p, line, propNames);
    }

    static void parseLine<T>(T t, string[] line, string[] propNames)
    {
        for(int i = 0;i<propNames.Length;i++)
        {
            string sprop = propNames[i];
            PropertyInfo prop = t.GetType().GetProperty(sprop);
            object val = Convert.ChangeType(line[i], prop.PropertyType);
            prop.SetValue(t, val );
        }
    }

    class Person
    {
        public string fname{get;set;}
        public string lname{get;set;}
        public int room {get;set;}
    }
```

Comment: This really is a comment, not much of answer (or maybe a link only answer)

Comment: can't write comments :(